# Wordpress fatal error from php protocol codes

Tags: plugins, php, wp-admin, errors

This is the website link: dormireacuba .it/

When I'm trying to visit this site then just showing some fatal errors

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_fix_server_vars() in /web/htdocs/www.dormireacuba.it/home/wp-settings.php:128 Stack trace: #0 /web/htdocs/www.dormireacuba.it/home/wp-config.php(209): require_once() #1 /web/htdocs/www.dormireacuba.it/home/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/web/htdocs/www...') #2 /web/htdocs/www.dormireacuba.it/home/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/web/htdocs/www...') #3 /web/htdocs/www.dormireacuba.it/home/index.php(140): require('/web/htdocs/www...') #4 {main} thrown in /web/htdocs/www.dormireacuba.it/home/wp-settings.php on line 128

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_get_server_protocol() in /web/htdocs/www.dormireacuba.it/home/wp-includes/functions.php:1412 Stack trace: #0 /web/htdocs/www.dormireacuba.it/home/wp-includes/functions.php(3474): status_header(500) #1 /web/htdocs/www.dormireacuba.it/home/wp-includes/functions.php(3421): _default_wp_die_handler('<div class="wp-...', 'WordPress &rsaq...', Array) #2 /web/htdocs/www.dormireacuba.it/home/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(233): wp_die(Object(WP_Error), '', Array) #3 /web/htdocs/www.dormireacuba.it/home/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(152): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_default_error_template(Array, false) #4 /web/htdocs/www.dormireacuba.it/home/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(57): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_error_template(Array, false) #5 [internal function]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #6 {main} thrown in /web/htdocs/www.dormireacuba.it/home/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1412
```

The code is from wp-settings.php on line 128

```
wp_fix_server_vars();
```

and The code is from wp-includes/functions.php on line 1412

```
$protocol      = wp_get_server_protocol();
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What was the state of the site before those errors? was it live? did someone install anything new/updated? did you upload this site from local to live?

Comment: the customer doesn't touch anything I think by 1 year

Comment: Most likely a wordpress update caused it, try reverting back to an older version, the version before the update. Follow [updating WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/)

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much

Comment: Now I have updated the WordPress files manually. And the first error has been gone. But the second error is still there.

Comment: Disable all plugins manualy by renaming each one, you can add `1` to the end on the plugin folder